# Unusal ports open in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, apple-silicon, monterey

So I was on my macbook air and I had just installed macOS monterey. I was a bit suspicious of some of the things running on the computer, so I decided to see all of the open ports. I found the command `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` to look for the listening ports. However, I got some strange output even though the only application open was the terminal:

```
launchd TCP localhost:8021 (LISTEN)
rapportd TCP *:49159 (LISTEN)
```

I did not understand what these two lines were, and why ports 8021 and 49159 were listening despite the firewall being on and strict. Is there a way to block these connections? If anyone could answer this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also blocked all incoming connections on the firewall, yet I still see these ports listening

Comment: For port 8021, is [this question](/questions/404346/what-is-intu-ec-client-listening-on-tcp-port-8021) related?

Comment: The only issue is that I never had ftp open on this computer, so I am a bit confused why it's listening on port 8021 (as per the top answer there) if there is no file sharing on (at least I don't believe so)

Comment: `rapportd` appears to have something to do with handing off phone calls between Apple devices; see ["What is rapportd and why does it want incoming network connections?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308294/what-is-rapportd-and-why-does-it-want-incoming-network-connections)

Comment: Ah, got you @GordonDavisson, I signed out of iMessage and disabled phone connection and then the port seemed to close so that front seems all good

Comment: Does anyone know though about port 8021, the post @gidds seems to have conflicting answers in the post

Comment: Port 8021 might be the FTP proxy built into macOS (I think it's part of Internet Sharing?). Run `sudo launchctl list com.apple.ftp-proxy`, and see if it gives you an error ("Could not find service...", in which case it's disabled) or lists its properties (in which case it's enabled).

Comment: @GordonDavisson yeah it listed the properties I believe (had stuff like wait false and the sockets). Is there a way to disable this in the macOS settings?

Comment: I think the FTP proxy gets turned on if you're running Internet Sharing -- are you? If that's why it's on, I'm not sure there's a good way to turn it off. I also don't know of a good reason to turn it off, since I'm pretty sure it's just a proxy -- something to help FTP connections find their way across the shared connection, not something that's actually allowing access to something on your computer.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you so much @GordonDavisson