# What are "netbiosd" and "rapportd"? Why are they asking for incoming network connections?

Tags: macos, network, permission, firewall

I was asked to allow/block netbiosd & rapportd, but I do not know what they are, so I block both of them. What are they, and blocking them is okay?

[image]

Comment: You should ask one question at a time - this is two questions - each of which is a duplicate [netbiosd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81751/should-i-block-incoming-connections-from-netbiosd/81757#81757) [rapportd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308294/237)

Answer (score 2):

rapportd is an application that serves Apple's "Handoff" connections from your phone, more details are [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308294/what-is-rapportd-and-why-does-it-want-incoming-network-connections)

netbios is an application to serve compatibility of file share application like Samba or SMB protocol more info about it can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#NetBIOS_name_vs_host_name). It is an old replacement of computer naming resolving across the network. How to disable netbios is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211927)

Answering the question: they require incoming connection in order to connect to your computer, rapportd for iMessage, phone calls, maybe clipboard sharing etc. and netbios for computer name resolution. Blocking or not it depends if you need those services or/and you are experiencing issues with them.